# $_SESSION values do not retain values when passed from another page

Tags: php, session

So I have a problem where I have several $_SESSION values defined and need to be sent to the next page. Here is a quick look at the meat of my problem.

**login.php**

```
    session_set_cookie_params(900, '/', 'localhost:8080/test/');
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['first_name'] = "Moe";
    $_SESSION['last_name']  = "Joe";
    header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/test/admin_console.php?" . SID);
    exit();

?>
```

On the next page, I expect my $_SESSION['first_name'] and $_SESSION['last_name'] to be defined as they have been set by the code above.  The following is the meat of my code in the next page

**admin_console.php**

```
    session_name('AdminLogin');
    session_start();
    #Set page title and include HTML header
    $page_title = 'Administrative Console';
    include('./header.inc');

    $mysession = session_get_cookie_params();

    $msg = $_SESSION['first_name'];
    echo "Is the thing set? " . $msg . "<br />";

?>
```

The problem is, i get the following error:
`*Notice: Undefined index: first_name in C:\wamp\www\test\admin_console.php on line xx*`

I can't for the life of me figure out why `$_SESSION['first_name']` wont retain its value from previous page. i have `session_start()` in every page and i even went as far as to add several lines to completely kill the session at the end of this page

```
<?php
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    setcookie('PHPSESSID', '', time()-300, '/', '', 0);
?>
```

So my echo statement should display the value that is entered in $_SESSION, but to no avail. Any help?

Comment: Remove session_name() call from the admin_console.php. Or add same line to the login.php: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

Answer (score 0):

OH MY GOD, it is the worst mistake in the world.

Google Chrome, for some reason, saves previous attempts or pages. So during my initial tests, the page failed.  But when I fixed the code, the browser still retained the old style.

I just now had this feeling in my gut to try the code in the Incognito mode, and it WORKED!

Lesson Learned: If your code looks perfect and you're still getting same error no matter what, try a different browser or clear out browser cache.

Answer (score -1):

It's just a notice (warning). You can set `error_reporting(7);` to get rid of this message.

Your code looks fine , check your php info "session section".